# Creating cookieless application on development machine with asp.net

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, cookieless

I am thinking about setting up a new domain to host static content on my website and have it cookieless just like Stackoverflow with their  [static domain](http://sstatic.net).
So before going ahead and buying the domain and setting it up I wanted to test it on my developement machine first under localhost (I have to mention that i am planning on having IIS running on my new domain for the static files).

I therefore created a new application under IIS and disabled session state and forms authentication. When my main application needs resources like css, images and js , I use the path to the "static" application where they are hosted.

The problem is that when I look at the request and the response for the requested files, they still have the session_id cookie defined as well as the asp.net authentication cookie.

Is it at all possible to accomplish what i am trying to do on a development machine or do i have to just go ahead and purchase the new domain which hopefully with make things right? I tried to read about cookieless domain but can't figure out what i might be missing.

Comment: You'll have better luck with this on stackoverflow

Comment: how can i move it over there? should i just post the question over there?

Answer (score 1):

To don't use the session state feature, put this in the `web.config` file:

```
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <sessionState mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

On IIS7/Windows 2008 you should disable session state all together for the site. That will disable cookies as well.

In the IIS Manager, select your site, under *ASP.NET* select *Session State* and choose *Not Enabled*.

Answer (score 1):

I setup a seperate site in iis with the cname (host: s.mysite.com, css.mysite.com and js.mysite.com)

In that site's configuration i use the following:

```
</system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
          <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00"></clientCache>
        </staticContent>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" />
        <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false">
        </caching>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```